# How to do seeding in EF Core 2.1

Tags: .net, .net-core

In my normal .NET framework, I used the following code in Configuration.cs:

```
protected override void Seed(Athlosify.Models.AthlosifyContext context)
    {
        var golfCourses = new List<GolfCourse>
        {
            new GolfCourse { Name = "Bonnie Doon Golf Club", Description = "N/A", Address = "38 Banks Ave", Suburb = "Pagewood", State="NSW", Postcode = "2035", Country = "Australia", Latitude=-33.935189, Longitude=151.222372  },
            new GolfCourse { Name = "Beverly Park Golf Club", Description = "N/A", Address = "87 Jubilee Avenue", Suburb = "Beverly Park", State="NSW", Postcode = "2217", Country = "Australia", Latitude=-33.975506, Longitude=151.131691  }

        };
        golfCourses.ForEach(s => context.GolfCourses.AddOrUpdate(p => p.GolfCourseID, s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var golfRoundCategories = new List<GolfRoundCategory>
        {
            new GolfRoundCategory { Name = "Competition - Stroke", Description = "N/A" },
            new GolfRoundCategory { Name = "Competition - Stableford", Description = "N/A" },
            new GolfRoundCategory { Name = "Competition - Ambrose", Description = "N/A" },
            new GolfRoundCategory { Name = "Competition - Foresome", Description = "N/A" },
            new GolfRoundCategory { Name = "Practice - 2 Ball Best Balls", Description = "N/A" },
            new GolfRoundCategory { Name = "Practice - 2 Ball Worst Balls", Description = "N/A" },
        };
        golfRoundCategories.ForEach(s => context.GolfRoundCategories.AddOrUpdate(p => p.GolfRoundCategoryID, s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var golfRounds = new List<GolfRound>
        {
            new GolfRound { Name = "Bonnie Doon GC Practice", Notes = "N/A", UserID = Guid.Parse("7dd950ad-d7b0-448a-b689-db3947e31bec"),
                        GolfCourseID = golfCourses.Single(c => c.Name == "Bonnie Doon Golf Club" ).GolfCourseID,
                        DailyHandicap = 21, GolfRoundCategoryID = golfRoundCategories.Single(c => c.Name == "Practice - 2 Ball Best Balls" ).GolfRoundCategoryID,
                        TeeOffUTC = DateTime.Parse("2018-07-22 15:00") },
        };
        golfRounds.ForEach(s => context.GolfRounds.AddOrUpdate(p => p.GolfRoundID, s));
        context.SaveChanges();
```

Trying to do seeding in .Net Core 2.1 plus how to get this value then:

**GolfCourseID = golfCourse.Single(c => c.Name == "Bonnie Doon Golf Club").GolfCourseID**

and

**GolfRoundCategoryID = golfRoundCategories.Single(c => c.Name == "Practice - 2 Ball Best Balls").GolfRoundCategoryID**

?!!?!

```
public static void Seed(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<GolfCourse>().HasData(
            new GolfCourse { Name = "Bonnie Doon Golf Club", Description = "N/A", Address = "38 Banks Ave", Suburb = "Pagewood", State = "NSW", Postcode = "2035", Country = "Australia", Latitude = -33.935189, Longitude = 151.222372 },
            new GolfCourse { Name = "Beverly Park Golf Club", Description = "N/A", Address = "87 Jubilee Avenue", Suburb = "Beverly Park", State = "NSW", Postcode = "2217", Country = "Australia", Latitude = -33.975506, Longitude = 151.131691 }

        );
        modelBuilder.Entity<GolfRoundCategory>().HasData(
            new GolfRoundCategory { Name = "Competition - Stroke", Description = "N/A" },
            new GolfRoundCategory { Name = "Competition - Stableford", Description = "N/A" },
            new GolfRoundCategory { Name = "Competition - Ambrose", Description = "N/A" },
            new GolfRoundCategory { Name = "Competition - Foresome", Description = "N/A" },
            new GolfRoundCategory { Name = "Practice - 2 Ball Best Balls", Description = "N/A" },
            new GolfRoundCategory { Name = "Practice - 2 Ball Worst Balls", Description = "N/A" }
        );

        modelBuilder.Entity<GolfRound>().HasData(
            new GolfRound
            {
                Name = "Bonnie Doon GC Practice",
                Notes = "N/A",
                UserID = Guid.Parse("7dd950ad-d7b0-448a-b689-db3947e31bec"),
                GolfCourseID = golfCourse.Single(c => c.Name == "Bonnie Doon Golf Club").GolfCourseID,
                DailyHandicap = 21,
                GolfRoundCategoryID = golfRoundCategories.Single(c => c.Name == "Practice - 2 Ball Best Balls").GolfRoundCategoryID,
                TeeOffUTC = DateTime.Parse("2018-07-22 15:00")
            },
        );

    }
```

Comment: Replaced that similar thing with seeding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF Core seed data is an integral part of migrations. Just like changes of DB schema changes, changes of seed data are detected and embedded in migrations. That being so, there's no *DbContext* around which would make possible to run queries or to retrieve IDs auto-generated by the DB engine.

You need to set explicit ID values for your auto-generated key columns to be able to reference those entities:

```
var golfCourse1 = new GolfCourse { GolfCourseID = 1, Name = "Bonnie Doon Golf Club", Description = "N/A", Address = "38 Banks Ave", Suburb = "Pagewood", State = "NSW", Postcode = "2035", Country = "Australia", Latitude = -33.935189, Longitude = 151.222372 };

modelBuilder.Entity<GolfCourse>().HasData(
    golfCourse1,
    // ...
);

var golfRoundCategory5 = new GolfRoundCategory { GolfRoundCategoryID = 5, Name = "Practice - 2 Ball Best Balls", Description = "N/A" };

modelBuilder.Entity<GolfRoundCategory>().HasData(
    // ...
    golfRoundCategory5,
    // ...
);

modelBuilder.Entity<GolfRound>().HasData(
    new GolfRound
    {
        Name = "Bonnie Doon GC Practice",
        Notes = "N/A",
        UserID = Guid.Parse("7dd950ad-d7b0-448a-b689-db3947e31bec"),
        GolfCourseID = golfCourse1.GolfCourseID,
        DailyHandicap = 21,
        GolfRoundCategoryID = golfRoundCategory5.GolfRoundCategoryID,
        TeeOffUTC = DateTime.Parse("2018-07-22 15:00")
    },
 );
```

Comment: That's a problem cause I'm using GUID to generate the ID. I guess I could explicitly generate the GUID.